# window.location.href not getting query string

Tags: javascript, window.location

I'm trying to test if the page has a certain query string in front of the address so I'm using `window.location.href` (or `window.location.search`) but it shows the domain followed by the file name (html file).

This is what I'm using:

```
var currURL = window.location.href;
```

I also tried to use the `setTimeout` fork as well, thinking the query string might be added later on the pipeline (I didn't develop the website so I don't know) but that's not the problem.

BUT WAIT! The most intriguing part is yet to come. If I do `window.location.href` on chrome's console I get the correct URL. What gives?

--

EDIT (duplicate justification): This is not a duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) because that question dealt with how to get individual strings and all. I tried that but my problem is that it relies on `window.location.href` as well, so it returns the null on the query string.

--

EDIT (more info): I'm not sure it will be useful for most of you, because the address is for a brazillian Portuguese website. [In any case, here is the page in question](http://www.cordvida.com.br/new/obrigado-por-seu-interesse?submissionGuid=22ed6a71-a4cf-4ef4-b5a0-0ab40c068bf6). There is a previews js error but I don't think it's interfering: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. Will have a look at that.

Comment: What about a JavaScript error if there is any?

Comment: Do you have something you can show us like a JS Fiddle or a link to the website, where you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Jamiec that's good to close it but issue seems anything else.